# Regular expression confiuration in FlumeNG

Tags: hadoop, analytics, hbase, flume

I am trying to load data from flat-file(log file ) into Hbase using Flume-ng(1.2) . Flat file has multiple columns each is colon(:) seperated , they all need to be loaded into seperate columns in HBASE. i  was checking the forums i found there is a jar from Apache to solve this issue (org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer) , but i am unable to find any confuration files or the usage in internet. If someone can help me with the configuration file ,that would be helpful

Contents in Flat file 
1:nn
2:pp
3:mm

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`RegexHbaseEventSerializer` has three configuration parameters you can set ([as described in the source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob_plain;f=flume-ng-sinks/flume-ng-hbase-sink/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/hbase/RegexHbaseEventSerializer.java)); these are:

```
/** Regular expression used to parse groups from event data. */
public static final String REGEX_CONFIG = "regex";

/** Whether to ignore case when performing regex matches. */
public static final String IGNORE_CASE_CONFIG = "regexIgnoreCase";

/** Comma separated list of column names to place matching groups in. */
public static final String COL_NAME_CONFIG = "colNames";
```

A sample configuration using `RegexHbaseEventSerializer` would be like this (partially quoting from [Cloudera's Flume and HBase presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mapredit/flume-and-hbase)):

```
host1.sources = src1
host1.sinks = sink1
host1.channels = ch1

host1.sources.src1.type = seq
host1.sources.src1.port = 25001
host1.sources.src1.bind = localhost
host1.sources.src1.channels = ch1

host1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
host1.sinks.sink1.channel = ch1
host1.sinks.sink1.table = test3
host1.sinks.sink1.columnFamily = testing

host1.sinks.sink1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer
host1.sinks.sink1.serializer.regex = X
host1.sinks.sink1.serializer.regexIgnoreCase = true
host1.sinks.sink1.serializer.colNames = column_1,column_2,column_3

host1.channels.ch1.type=memory10
```